# Android BluetoothGatt super methods?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

When extending `BluetoothGattCallback` should implementors invoke super methods?

Example:

```
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                  BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, 
                                  int status) {
     // Is this needed?
     super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);

     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it seems unnecessary to call super methods.
`BluetoothGattCallback` class is abstract and all its methods are empty.

**Edit:**

`BluetoothGattCallback` is part of Android SDK and above the native layer.
It's methods are called from `BluetoothGatt` class which handles callbacks from the native layer and converts them into calls to `BluetoothGattCallback` methods.

If you wonder why `BluetoothGattCallback` is an abstract class with empty implementations and not an interface. It's probably because it has too many callback methods, so implementing an interface would cause an unnecessary bloat in the code.

**Edit2:**

Official reference for this is little difficult to get. [Compatiblity definition](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/cs//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) for hardware manufactures declares that they must implement Android APIs in the form declared in Android SDK.

Note that the underlaying native layer is connected via Android's Binder mechanism.

Comment: It could be that the implementation is native per manufacturer? That is my fear. That there is some native underlying implementation

Comment: I don't think that would be a problem. There's surely an underlaying native layer, but that's already handled in `BluetoothGatt` class. I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Great, I'm accepting the answer but could you please put in some official reference?

Answer (score 0):

After watching the source code of `BluetoothGattCallBack`, it seems that there is no need to invoke super method.

For `BluetoothGattCallBack` is an abstract class and also `onCharacteristicWrite` is an empty method in it.

Here is the source code of it:

```
/**
 * Callback indicating the result of a characteristic write operation.
 *
 * <p>If this callback is invoked while a reliable write transaction is
 * in progress, the value of the characteristic represents the value
 * reported by the remote device. An application should compare this
 * value to the desired value to be written. If the values don't match,
 * the application must abort the reliable write transaction.
 *
 * @param gatt GATT client invoked {@link BluetoothGatt#writeCharacteristic}
 * @param characteristic Characteristic that was written to the associated
 *                       remote device.
 * @param status The result of the write operation
 *               {@link BluetoothGatt#GATT_SUCCESS} if the operation succeeds.
 */
public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                  BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
}
```

Comment: Yeah, there is a discussion about this in the accepted answer above